# Is there a list of NICs that work with linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, networkcard

I built a new computer and want to install Linux on it. I loaded a couple different flavors and they detect there is a NIC but it won't connect to the network. It looks like it tries and tries but never connects. Network is using DHCP so not getting an address shouldn't be the issue. I figured the drivers might be an issue but the NIC on the mobo didn't have linux drivers so I bought a PCI NIC that people seemed to not have issues with, by searching the internet. I bought a D-Link DGE-530T. I put it in and it's acting the same way. I install windows and the intgrated NIC works fine so it can't be the hardware itself. Anyone use this D-Link card before or anyone have any advice on what to try? Went to the D-Link site to get the latest drivers too.

Also, looking at the README in the drivers folder, it references files that aren't even included so I don't get what that's about.

Comment: Almost all network cards (PCI and internal) should work with a modern Linux kernel.  What is your kernel version (found by typing `uname -r` in a terminal)?

Comment: Also, make sure your router isn't applying a MAC address filtering that's preventing new wired connections.

Comment: Last used Ubuntu 12.10 so it would be v3.5.
Shouldn't be using MAC filtering as I've never turned it on. My router also only has filtering for wireless connections.

Comment: @drs, if there were a network issue OP would be having problems on Windows as well.

Comment: @JoelDavis right, I forgot he tested on Windows.

Comment: You can try putting the output of `dmesg` as well as `cat /var/log/messages` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) after attempting to connect to the network.  These are where kernel and system logs are kept and they may contain helpful error messages.

Comment: If you see a line with "eth0" in /proc/net/dev then it's not the driver, it's something else.

Comment: Try configuring the NIC with a static IP. You might also want to turn down the speed to 10Mbps/half-duplex and disable auto-negotiation protocol -with `ethtool` - some NIC/router combinations don't handle noisy lines (like the ethernet cable running behind a TV or close to mains) well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing Linux drivers on [the official D-Link Website](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/dge-530t-dge-530t-32-bit-10-100-1000-base-t-pci-adapter) and it's going back to 2008. If it's a consumer grade NIC that's been out for five years or more, Linux is going to support it out of the box. Something else must be going on.

First things first, It would see if the NIC shows up on lspci, and if it does see if the associated module is loaded ("lspci -v" gives you the first and the module name and "lsmod | grep " tells you if its loaded). If it's recognized and the module for it is loaded, then I would check link status with ethtool and if that shows a link detected and a speed negotiated, try to run "dhclient" on the interface from the command line and try to see if it tells you anything informative at that point.

That's the most advice I can give without knowing what the above results are.

Comment: Yes the NIC shows up with the lspci command but not when I use lsmod. How can I load it?

Comment: I take that back. I was looking for something like "dlink" in the lsmod output. In "lspci" the module for both the NICs I have is "r8169". The "lsmod" output for "r8169" is "size: 61650 used by: 0"

Comment: I do not have ethtools installed but using "cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate" it claims the NIC is "up". Running "dhclient" alone does not do anything. Is there any switches or anything I should use? Thank you.

Comment: To send dhcp requests over a particular interface use something like `dhclient eth0` What distro is this BTW?

Comment: BTW a better sysfs attribute to check is "speed" if it's detected a  link and negotiated a speed it should be a non-zero value.

Comment: I did check the speed as well and it said "1000", so gigabit. I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Will be going to 13.04 though since that was just released and I haven't been able to actually get the computer up and running.

Comment: What was the output of dhclient ?

Comment: No output for dhclient. It just hangs at execution.

Comment: OK sounds like there's a problem with dhclient then, which is probably why it's hanging on your from the GUI. There may be some kind of bug in it, in which case going to a higher or lower version number might work around it.

Comment: I did try ubuntu 13.04 and it's still doing the same thing. I thought since it seemed like a DHCP issue, I could just statically assign an address. I did and for all intents and purposes it showed it was connected to the network, but it isn't. I can't get to internet and can't ping anything even on my network.

Comment: Did you remember to set the default gateway and DNS servers?

Comment: Yes, for sure. I verified the info from laptop I use as well.

Comment: I'm kind of shooting in the dark at this point but I did find this: http://adam.rosi-kessel.org/weblog/2008/06/21/a-much-simpler-fix-for-the-r8169-link-down-problem . Basically, he's using ethtool to turn autonegotiation off. My experience is more with RHEL but I'd imagine the binary package for ethtool is on the install disc somewhere. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.